# I am working on a flask API for LIke, Dislike and Comment but i have some errors when i want to check if recipe has been liked before

Tags: python, peewee

```
@app.route("/comment/<int:id>", methods=['POST'])   
@jwt_required()
def create_comment(id):
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    comment = request.form['comment']

    if not comment:
        return jsonify('Comment cannot be empty.')
    if not Recipe.select().where(Recipe.id == id).exists():
        return 'Recipe ID does not Exist', 404
    recipe_id = Recipe.get(id)
    new_comment = Comment.create(recipe_id = recipe_id ,text=comment, 
    poster_id=current_user )
    return jsonify('Comment posted'), 201



@app.route("/like/<int:id>", methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def like(id):
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    recipe_id = Recipe.get(id)
    
    like = Like.select().where((Recipe.poster_id == current_user) & (Recipe.id == 
    id))

    if not Recipe.select().where(Recipe.id == id).exists():
        return jsonify('Recipe ID does not Exist'), 404

    elif like:
            like = Like.delete().where((Recipe.poster_id == current_user) & 
            (Recipe.id == id))
            like.execute()
    else:
        like = Like.create(recipe_id = recipe_id , poster_id=current_user )
        

        return jsonify(f'You have liked the recipe with ID:  {recipe_id}'), 200

    
 
@app.route("/dislike/<int:id>", methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def dislike(id):
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    get_recipe_id = Recipe.get(id)
    if not Recipe.select().where(Recipe.id == id).exists():
        return 'Recipe ID does not Exist', 404
    dislike = Dislike.create(recipe_id = get_recipe_id , poster_id=current_user )
    return jsonify(f'You have disliked the recipe with ID:  {get_recipe_id}'), 200
```

When i try the like route i get the following error:

```
peewee.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 't2.poster_id' in 'where clause'")
```

This route works the way i want it when i query an ID present in the database. but When i try using a random ID that is not present in the db, i get the following error:

```
model.RecipeDoesNotExist: <Model: Recipe> instance matching query does not exist:
            SQL: SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`name`, `t1`.`description`, 
`t1`.`ingredients`, `t1`.`process`,
            `t1`.`post_date`, `t1`.`poster_id`, `t1`.`image` FROM `recipe` AS `t1` 
 WHERE (`t1`.`id` = %s) LIMIT %s
            OFFSET %s
            Params: [22, 1, 0]
```

I am using peewee and MySQL. Below is the structure of my model. The database is in good shape as all my tables take data but the error output is from PostMan.

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
        
class Users(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(primary_key=True)
    fullname = CharField()
    username = CharField()
    email = CharField()
    password_harsh = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    gender = CharField()

    
    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('Password is not readabale attribure!')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_harsh = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_harsh, password)



class Recipe(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField()
    description = CharField()
    ingredients = CharField()
    process = TextField()
    post_date = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL('DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')])
    poster_id = ForeignKeyField(Users, backref='recipe', lazy_load=False)
    image = CharField()


class Comment(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(primary_key=True)
    text = CharField()
    recipe_id = ForeignKeyField(Recipe, backref='comment', lazy_load=False)
    post_date = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL('DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')])
    poster_id = ForeignKeyField(Users, backref='comment', lazy_load=False)
    


class Like(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = ForeignKeyField(Recipe, backref='comment', lazy_load=False)
    post_date = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL('DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')])
    poster_id = ForeignKeyField(Users, backref='like', lazy_load=False)
    
class Dislike(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = ForeignKeyField(Recipe, backref='comment', lazy_load=False)
    post_date = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL('DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')])
    poster_id = ForeignKeyField(Users, backref='dislike', lazy_load=False)
```

Comment: Share your Peewee models then.....

Comment: I have done that in edit.

Answer (score 0):

For your second error, you're getting a `DoesNotExist` exception because as you explained you're looking for an item that doesn't exist in your database. If you want to handle the error correctly, you should do something like this:

```py
try:
    Recipe.get_by_id(9999)
except Recipe.DoesNotExist:
    # Handle it here
```

Or you could also do it like so:

```py
Recipe.get_or_none(Recipe.id == 9999)
```

Which will return `None` if the recipe doesn't exist.

I'm not sure this answers your question as I am not sure what your question is in the first place.